# Are two following mv operations in bash script safe?

Tags: bash, mv

I have two files `new.txt` and `old.txt`. In the end of my script I want to rename these files, `old.txt -> old_1.txt` and `new.txt -> old.txt`. These are two lines of my script:

```
mv old.txt old_1.txt
mv new.txt old.txt
```

My question is, if it is safe to use these two mv commands and if there is not possible, that second mv command will be executed (in some specific condition) earlier than first?

The script is executed once a day, and I noticed that `old_1.txt` has date of modification from previous day (it wasn't replaced). However if I have run this script manually, the `old_1.txt` has been modified already. Could someone explain me, where could be a problem?

Comment: consider testing file name already exist before renaming. search for log rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `mv` will use the date of `new.txt` for `old.txt`. When you say you run the script manually I assume you are creating `new.txt` (or you have opened `new.txt` with some text editor that has saved) thus having todays date. when you run `mv` on this new `new.txt` it will cause `old.txt` to have todays date.